# Prevent menu list from wrapping

Tags: html, css

Hi there i made a simple nav bar in CSS and HTML. I need it to be completely horizontal The only problem is if u are zoomed in it start to move around. See the example below. Just wondering how to stop this. Also how do i put the text in the middle of the box? as u can see its a bit above the middle near the top. Thanks for the help

Here is the example 
http://jsfiddle.net/NfHFH/

Css:

```
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
li {
    float:left;
}
a:link, a:visited {
    display:block;
    width:155px;
    height: 60px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color:#98bf21;
    text-align:center;
    padding:4px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
a:hover, a:active {
    background-color:#7A991A;
}
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: give width to your `ul` example: `ul {width:960px}` [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NfHFH/1/)

Comment: Sorry i dident see that question :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the width of your `<ul>` if you don't want it to wrap around.

```
ul
{
    width:820px;
}
```

To center the text, set `line-height` to the same as `height`

```
a:link,a:visited
{
    line-height: 60px;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dnVNd/1/)

Comment: Thats great , thank u and do u know anything about the text? and how to center it?

Comment: to center the text vertically, set the line-height to the same height as the links.

a:link { height:100px; line-height:100px; }

Comment: Thank u very big help by both of u

Comment: If we helped then select an answer as correct :)

Comment: Cant as it says i need 2 wait for a bit before i can

Answer (score 0):

Or set a container with a width.

```
.wrapper {
 width:800px   

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h4CHr/